# How to get execution time of all methods executed during execution of specific method?

Tags: c#, postsharp

How to get execution time of all methods executed during execution of specific method using PostSharp?

Answer (score 1):

When using PostSharp, you typically apply the aspect directly to the method which requires some specific additional behavior. So, for measuring an execution time of a method, you would apply a profiling aspect to that method. You can find a sample of a custom profiling aspect on our samples website: [PostSharp.Samples.Profiling](http://samples.postsharp.net/f/PostSharp.Samples.Profiling/)

I understand however that you need to measure the execution time of each method that is called from the aspect's target method. For this purpose you can try to implement an aspect provider and use the [PostSharp.Reflection.ReflectionSearch](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_reflection_reflectionsearch) search class to find all the used methods.

```
[PSerializable]
public class ProfileProviderAttribute : MethodLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        MethodBase targetMethod = (MethodBase) targetElement;
        foreach (var codeReference in ReflectionSearch.GetDeclarationsUsedByMethod(targetMethod))
        {
            if (codeReference.UsedDeclaration.MemberType == MemberTypes.Method)
            {
                yield return new AspectInstance(codeReference.UsedDeclaration, new ProfileAttribute());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even if I use reflection, how can I trace methods called from methods executed during execution of specific ? I mean how can I trace execution time of 2nd, 3rd or nth level method calls ?

Comment: The code sample demonstrates an approach you can experiment with. For example, you could keep searching for used methods at depth 2, 3 and so on. Please note, that this would work only with the methods declared in the currently processed assembly. In general, the answer is that the common use case with PostSharp is to apply the profiling aspect to the method which execution time you need to measure.